# Manipulating XML with Dom

Tags: php, xml, dom

i'm trying to manipulate an xml by adding a few custom tags.

I managed to add a custom Element and a TextNode on it, but it gets rendered at the very bottom of the XML.

How do i add this custom tag as a child of another tag? i tried using the following code:

`$product_record = $xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('product_record');`

and then

`$text = $test->appendChild($product_record);`

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's where i got stuck:
http://viper-7.com/CsRNHU

How do i get the test tag to be rendered inside product_record?

Thanks, 
Thales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your full example you add the new element to the document itselt, not the fetched node.

The getElementsByTagName() method returns a list of nodes, not a single node, so you need to use a loop or fetch a specific element from the list.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($url);

$products = $xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('product_record');

foreach ($products as $product) {
  $test = $product
      ->appendChild($xml->createElement('test'))
      ->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("testing"));
}

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

The DOMDocument::create*() methods create specific nodes and return them. The appendChild() method adds it to a parent node and returns the added node.

Your example returns an UTF-16 encoded XML. Import it into an UTF-8 XML document if you want to change the encoding:

```
$utf8 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$utf8->appendChild($utf8->importNode($xml->documentElement, TRUE));
```

Demo: http://viper-7.com/1eCPeo

Comment: That's great! it just works.
For the purpose of learning more about what i can do with this. I tried modifying your code to show the $product_id in one tag that i'm creating. When i get this working i want to pull a variable from another xml.
At the moment it doesnt work if i try to put the product_id for example. Any idea what am i missing here?
http://viper-7.com/RTbwly

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` return a list of elements, not a single product id. Use Xpath (`DOMXpath::evaluate()`) to fetch data from a XML DOM http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[xml]%20[php]%20xpath%20evaluate